# decrease font size of different styles on active

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assume I have two or more button styles:

```
button style1{
    font-size: 20px;
}
button style2{
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

I want to style the button tag so when buttons (with the different styles) are active, the font size decreace by 4px.

```
button:active{
    font-size: "-=4px"
}
```

what is the simplest way to do it? can i do it in pure css?

Comment: This is not possible in pure css.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, so the initial font-size of the button is 24px, but when active, 20px.

```css
button.size-changing {
  font-size: 24px;
}

button.size-changing:active {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="size-changing"> Press me </button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I wanted, I don't want all the buttons to have the same font-size but I do want its font-size to be dynamically decrease by 4 on active.
so first button with font-size: 24px becomes 20, the second with font-size: 20 becomes 16px

Comment: Do you want me to change the code so the button will have the class you want? If so just tell me the class name and I will edit my answer. @AbdallahBarghouti

Comment: @smuteanu I have lots of buttons so this approach wont be effective

Comment: Just edited the code. Hope this works well for you now! :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but it work. I made a sample JS code to see if it would work for you. I hope I have been helpful.

```js
function autoStyle() {
    // Style name and Font size
    var arr = [
        ["style1", 20],
        ["style2", 24],
        ["style3", 28],
        ["style4", 32],
    ]

    // active style -4px
    var num = 4;

    ////////////////
    var textstl = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        textstl += '.' + arr[i][0] + '{ font-size: ' + arr[i][1] + 'px; } .' + arr[i][0] + ':active { font-size: ' + (arr[i][1] - num) + 'px; } '
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += '<style>' + textstl + '</style>'
}

autoStyle();
```

```html
<button class="style1">Text style 1</button>
<button class="style2">Text style 2</button>
<button class="style3">Text style 3</button>
<button class="style4">Text style 4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible with calc and var as shown in the snippet. Just assign a different local value for a common css var in the individual classes, and calculate the change for that locally scoped but commonly used var in the button selector.

However, I think this falls under the 'should you?' category of interactions. I personally don't like the idea of a button's text size changing on hover, focus, or active and as shown in the snippet there are some concessions you have to make to prevent layout shift for items below the buttons.

```css
button.style1 {
  --fontSize: 16px
}

button.style2 {
  --fontSize: 20px
}

button.style3 {
  --fontSize: 24px
}

button.style4 {
  --fontSize: 36px
}

button.style5 {
  --fontSize: 50px
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(var(--fontSize) * 3);
  width: calc(var(--fontSize) * 10);
  font-size: var(--fontSize)
}

button:active {
  font-size: calc(var(--fontSize) - 4px)
}
```

```html
<button class="style1">I'm button style 1!</button>

<button class="style2">I'm button style 2!</button>

<button class="style3">I'm button style 3!</button>

<button class="style4">I'm button style 4!</button>

<button class="style5">I'm button style 5!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do small calculations in css use the calc() function.

When referencing css variables use another pair of ().
To store css variables. Do the following

- In the root of the css add variable name
- Make sure the name starts with --
- When referencing the variable start with var(VARIABLE_NAME)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties - CSS VARIABLES
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp - CSS CALC FUNCTION

```css
:root {
  --button-size: 20px;
}
button.style1 {
  font-size: var(--button-size);
}

button.style2 {
  font-size: var(--button-size);
}

button.style3 {
  font-size: var(--button-size);
}
button:focus {
  font-size: calc((var(--button-size))-4px);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="style1">button 1</button>
  <button class="style2">button 2</button>
  <button class="style3">button 3</button>
</body>
```